# More efficient way to reformat text file with unequal amounts of whitespaces and then convert to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, reformatting

I attempted to write some code that would help me reformat my .txt file so that I can convert it to a .csv. However, the .txt has inconsistent amount of spaces and I attempted to make a way that would help replace the spaces with a comma.

I've tried multiple ways of replacing, but haven't come up with a conclusion yet. I also tried searching for string literals that would separate the columns, but haven't found any such as \t. I'm not worried about the first row (names of columns) because I'm renaming them anyways. The text file looks something like this:

```
 num1  num2   num3
 2323  33232  323232
 434    4556    3432
 43434 34343  434343
```

```
    for line in in_file:
        line1 = line.strip(' ')
        line2 = line1.replace('    ', ',')
        line3 = line2.replace('   ', ',')
        line4 = line3.replace('  ', ',')
        line5 = line4.replace(' ', ',')
        out_file.writelines(line5)
```

It prints out correctly, but it's not efficient since it only replaces a certain amount of spaces and if I get a file with more, I have to manually add the code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of strings to do this.

`str.split` produces a list of the "words" in your string, with no whitespace

```
>>> s = 'This is   a  long   string 1234  '
>>> s.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'string', '1234']
```

Once you have such a list you could use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method of strings to make a single comma-separated string:

```
>>> ','.join(s.split())
'This,is,a,long,string,1234'
```

However you might be better of using Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.  It will create a csv file and automatically handle things like embedded commas, which could cause problems otherwise.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('myfile.txt') as f, open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as o:
...     writer = csv.writer(o)
...     for line in f:
...         writer.writerow(line.split())
... 
16  
19
15
20
>>>
```

```
$  cat out.csv 
num1,num2,num3
2323,33232,323232
434,4556,3432
43434,34343,434343
```